# Using "Koa-Rewrite" AssertionError: app.use(rewrite) requires a generator function

Tags: javascript, node.js, koa

I am using Koa@1 and koa-rewrite@1 and try to implement functionality like this.

rewritelogic.js

```
const rewrite = require('koa-rewrite');
function rewriteLogic(){
  rewrite('/english/experience/dev1', '/english/experience/dev');
}

module.exports = {
  rewriteLogic,
}
```

And then use this file in my app.js

```
app.use(rewrite.rewriteLogic)
```

But I am facing this error

```
AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: app.use() requires a generator function
```

Can you help me on this ?

I removed this error by providing generator function but then rewrite functionality did not worked.

```
const rewrite = require('koa-rewrite');
function* rewriteLogic(next){
  rewrite('/english/experience/dev1', '/english/experience/dev');
  yield next;
}
module.exports = {
  rewriteLogic,
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solved this issue, we can do something like this.

```
const rewrite = require('koa-rewrite');
const rewriteRule =  rewrite('/english/experience/dev1', '/english/experience/dev')

module.exports = {
  rewriteRule,
}
```

Thanks